# this script disables left click without any reason

Tags: javascript

I have this script:

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('workspace').oncontextmenu = function(){
    return false;
    }
}

function click(e) {
    if (navigator.appName == 'Netscape' && e.which == 3) {
       window.location.reload();
       return false;
else {
    if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer' && event.button==2)
       window.location.reload();
       return false;
}
return true;
}
document.onmousedown=click;
```

The `workspace` is id of my `<body>` element. Basically this script does is, it reloads the current page when right clicked on the page. I'm happy with it, this is all I want.

But this script is having a bug. The problem is the **left click** is disabled. I have some text on webpage but the you can select the text with this script enabled.

I have no much experience with JavaScript but I tried removing the last line of the script. When I did so the left click started working and I can select the text, but soon I noted that reload does not works.

Comment: What's that a weird user interface behavior? Btw, nobody uses Netscape any more - your script won't work anywhere

Comment: I would be surprised and confused if some pages started reloading when I right-click. Don't do this, there's no reason to.

Comment: @You Its not a regular page. I'm working on an browser based application. Nothing to be surprised of.

Comment: **nobody uses Netscape any more - your script won't work anywhere**, please tell me what to do now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be because of click function `return false` in the third line.
you need `}` before `else {` and need to wrap with `{` `}` for last `if` block.

something like this should be ok.

```
function click(e) {
  if (navigator.appName == 'Netscape' && e.which == 3) {
     window.location.reload()
     return false;
  } else {
     if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer' && event.button==2) {
       window.location.reload();
       return false;
     }
  }
  return true;
}
```